# Unable to run the scrapy spyder from a script

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to run a scrapy spider from a python script as recommended in the [official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script), but this does not seem to work. Here is my folder structure:

```
root
│   scrapy.cfg
│   start_spider.py
│
└───salewhale
    │   items.py
    │   middlewares.py
    │   pipelines.py
    │   settings.py
    │   __init__.py
    │   
    └───spiders
            lavazza.py
            __init__.py
```

**start_spider.py**

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.crawler import Crawler, CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

items = []
def collect_items(item, response, spider):
    items.append(item)

crawler = Crawler('lavazza')
crawler.signals.connect(collect_items, signals.item_scraped)

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(crawler)
process.start()  # the script will block here until the crawling is finished

# at this point, the "items" variable holds the scraped items
```

**lavazza.py**

```
import scrapy
from salewhale.items import SalewhaleItem

class LavazzaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    ...
```

I'm able to run the spider just fine with this command `scrapy crawl lavazza`
I'm also quite new to python :-)

When I run the script in the root, I get this attribute error

```
python .\start_spider.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\start_spider.py", line 9, in <module>
    crawler = Crawler('lavazza')
  File "\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.spidercls.update_settings(self.settings)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'update_settings'
```

Changing the `crawler` to  `Crawler('LavazzaSpider')` results in the same error

**LATER EDIT :**
I've tried running the spider another way, by importing the LavazzaSpider class, but this not work either
**start_spider_v2.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from salewhale.spiders.lavazza import LavazzaSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'items.json'
})

process.crawl(LavazzaSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

this is the output

```
> python .\start_spider_v2.py
2019-12-10 12:08:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.7.3 started (bot: scrapybot)
...
2019-12-10 12:08:51 [salewhale.spiders.lavazza] DEBUG: start_requests, setting the location ...
Unhandled error in Deferred:
2019-12-10 12:08:51 [twisted] CRITICAL: Unhandled error in Deferred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 184, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 188, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1613, in unwindGenerator
    return _cancellableInlineCallbacks(gen)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1529, in _cancellableInlineCallbacks
    _inlineCallbacks(None, g, status)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
  File "root\salewhale\spiders\lavazza.py", line 25, in start_requests
    return [scrapy.FormRequest(location_url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.start_crawl)]
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 28, in __init__
    super(FormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 63, in _set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
builtins.TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:

2019-12-10 12:08:51 [twisted] CRITICAL: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\crawler.py", line 87, in crawl
    start_requests = iter(self.spider.start_requests())
  File "root\salewhale\spiders\lavazza.py", line 25, in start_requests
    return [scrapy.FormRequest(location_url, formdata=form_data, callback=self.start_crawl)]
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\form.py", line 28, in __init__
    super(FormRequest, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25, in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "\Python37\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 63, in _set_url
    raise TypeError('Request url must be str or unicode, got %s:' % type(url).__name__)
TypeError: Request url must be str or unicode, got NoneType:
```

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to run the spider with the second version by adding the project settings
**start_spider_v2.py**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from salewhale.spiders.lavazza import LavazzaSpider

process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'json',
    'FEED_URI': 'items.json'
})

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(LavazzaSpider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

I still have issues with the first version :-(